# Celery ImportError: No module named tasks

Tags: django, celery

I'm creating a test scenario for Celery/RabbitMQ/Django.  After browsing/reading the various posts similar to mine, I found this one, the closest, but still does not help me.  I'm having the "ImportError: no module named tasks" error when executing celery worker.

Celery: 3.1.5 (not dj-celery)
Django: 1.5.5

#### Project structure:

```
testcele/ (project name)
  mycelery/ (myapp)
    __init__
    tasks

  testcele/
    __init__
    celery_task
    settings
```

#### testcele/testcele/celery_task:

```
  from __future__ import absolute_import
  import os
  from celery import Celery, task, current_task
  from django.conf import settings

  os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'testcele.settings')

  app = Celery('testcele', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//',
                include=['tasks'])

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      app.start()    

  # Using a string here means the worker will not have to
  # pickle the object when using Windows.
  app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
  app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

#### testcele/testcele/**init**.py:

```
  from __future__ import absolute_import
  from .celery_task import app as celery_app
```

#### mycelery/tasks.py:

```
  from __future__ import absolute_import
  from celery import Celery, task, current_task, shared_task


  @shared_task()
  def create_models():
    .
    .
    .
```

I'm running: "celery worker -A testcele -l INFO", at the "testcele/" sub-dir.  I have also tried running from testcele/testcel sub-dir, from testcele/mycelery, replacing "testcele" on the celery worker command with "tasks" or "mycelery".  Obviously, this gives other errors.

What I am missing?

Thanks, Ricardo

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try adding a `__init__.py` file in your `mycelery` folder to make it a module. If that didn't work specify the tasks when defining your `app`. Like so:

```
app = Celery('testcele', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://guest@localhost//',
                include=['mycelery.tasks'])
```

Comment: the '__init__.py' file is indeed in the mycelery app folder.  Since it's empty, I did not include it in the question (I just edited it to show it).

Comment: include=['mycelery.tasks'] instead of include=['tasks'] ?